# ajax-injected form value not read by jQuery

Tags: jquery

**Problem summary:**

When drop-down is changed, jQuery fires AJAX to get PMs for selected project. The number of PMs already on the project is in PHP var `$num_pms`. (In AJAX, below, this is inserted as the value for the 2nd hidden input field #num_pms.)

In the AJAX success callback fn, `input#num_pms.val()` is read and used to init a counter -- but the number is always wrong.

To troubleshoot, I am attempting to read that value from `input#num_pms`, increment it and re-write it into `input#test`. However, after the form is submitted the value of test is empty. *BUT*, *weird*, the value of `input#num_pms` is correct!

I must be doing the wrong thing to read `input#num_pms` field value...?

---

HTML: A drop-down fires jQuery to run AJAX search. Results put into #reportstable div.

```
Project*:<br />
<?php include 'inc/widgets/dropdown_all_projects.php';?>

<form action="" method="post" name="updatepm" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="TheForm">
    <div id="reportstable">
    </div>
</form>
```

---

AJAX:

```
$project_num = $_POST['project_num'];
$project_id = get_project_id_from_project_num($project_num);

$aPMs = get_climgr_for_project($project_id,'user_id','first_name','last_name');
$num_pms = mysql_num_rows($aPMs);


//>Snippet< -- Inject following markup into #reportstable div.
echo
'<th width="50">
    Action
    <input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="'.$project_id.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="num_pms" id="num_pms" value="'.$num_pms.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" id="test" value="">
</th>
';
```

---

jQuery: Fires AJAX, returns results into #reportstable

```
$('#project_pick').change(function(e) {
    $('#project_pick').css('width', '500');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/ax_all_ajax_fns.php", 
        data: "project_num=" + $(this).val(),
        success:function(data){
            $('#reportstable').html(data);

            //Tried adding this first
            var count = $('#num_pms').val() + 1;
            $('#test').val(count);

            //Tried this after above wouldn't work. It didn't either.
            //var count = 80;
        } //END success fn
    }); //END $.ajax()
}); //END dropdown .change() event
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var count = parseInt($('#num_pms').val()) + 1;
```

Also make sure to have only one `#num_pms` element in your DOM.

Comment: Thanks. That was part of the answer. The other part was that for some reason my changes to the javascript file were not taking effect. For example, I deleted the entire body of the ajax success callback fn, then saved changes, Ctrl+F5 refreshed, and the #reportstable div was still getting populated, somehow. To solve that I had to begin version-numbering the .js file (eg. updatepm3.js) But your answer put me onto the right track and I am gr8ful. (Oh, and another part of the answer is that parseInt !== ParseInt).